# Error message - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My procedure is failing with the following error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure  Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'

The procedure is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[JobsStatusView]'))
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'DROP view [dbo].[JobsStatusView]'

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE VIEW JobsStatusView AS
SELECT AL.MAC,AL.AssemblyLineId,
AL.Name as AssemblyName,AL.SiteId,AL.IsActive,AL.IsRegistered,AL.IsOnline,
JB.Name as JobName,JB.Goal,JB.[Status],JB.Id as JobId,Jb.StartTime as JobStartTime,JB.Endtime as JobEndTime,JB.JobType,JB.Id as jobtypeid,
PT.Id as PartId,PT.[SKU] As PartSKU,PT.[Name] As PartName,JB.TargetCycleTime,PT.EquipmentCycleTime,JB.SlowCycleLimit,JB.SmallStopLimit,JB.BreakDownLimit,PT.Material,PT.GoodPartScaleFactor,PT.RejectionScaleFactor,
PT.CompanyId,
(select count(eventid) from EventStreams es where es.jobid=jb.id and es.EventType=''Pulse'') as GoodCount,
(select count(eventid) from EventStreams es where es.jobid=jb.id and es.EventType=''RejectionPulse'') as RejectedCount,
(select count(eventid) from EventStreams es where es.jobid=jb.id and es.EventType=''JobBreakDown'') as DownTimeCount,
 sm.Machine_Id,sm.Station_Id,OR.Id as OrderId,OR.CustomerId as CustomerId,OR.ProductId as ProductId,OR.DeliveryDate as DeliveryDate,OR.Quantity as Quantity
from Jobs JB
inner join AssemblyLines AL on JB.AssemblyLineId = AL.AssemblyLineId
Inner Join Sites S on AL.SiteId= s.Id
left Join Machines m on AL.AssemblyLineId   =m.AssemblyLineId
left Join StationMachines sm on m.Id    = sm.Machine_Id
Inner Join parts PT on JB.PartId = PT.Id
left Join Orders OR on JB.OrderId=OR.Id'
```

Comment: `OR` is a SQL reserved word.  Use another alias for `Orders`.

Comment: You could use brackets around the troublesome alias, e.g. `... Orders as [Or] on JB.OrderId = [Or].Id;`, but life is easier if you avoid object names that match keywords.

Comment: Its working..... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the OR keyword for the table alias. This is a reserved word.
You need to replace all occurrences of "OR" of this table with a different name.

[Reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) in tsql.

Comment: Its  working.. Thanks!!